# is it possible to use usb as boot partition?

Tags: dual-boot

what I exactly mean is like when u want to dual boot Linux with windows (windows is installed first) u make a bootable USB and boot from that and install the Linux.
in Linux there are some different partitions like root and boot
what I'm trying to do is to create that boot partition in USB and the files installed in the storage of PC so when I turn on the PC normally it boots from boot partition of windows and when I insert the USB and then boot it boots from USB (the USB has higher priority than hard drive in bios settings)
Is that Even Possible?
sorry if I could not explain it right
so just ask me about anything u need to know
my PC is BIOS legacy

Comment: Look into persistent USB.

Comment: Yes, as suggested by David, you can have a **persistent live system** in a USB drive. You can install program packages and you can store data files there. In Windows you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) and in Ubuntu [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). - Another alternative is to have an **installed system** (installed like into an internal drive, but in this case into the USB drive). One easy way to do it is to start from a compressed image file. [See this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

Comment: Yes... I've used a floppy drive on one system to boot a system where I was told I couldn't create/change a bootable partition on the internal drive (*so insert the floppy & it loaded after floppy-read & track-advance noises of course*) and there were no unused USB ports thus USB-media wasn't easily usable (*but this device was old enough to still have a floppy drive!*). **You can use whatever media your system will boot from**, but the more unusual it is; the more difficult setup (*and even maintenance*) will be  (*I'd hate to fix the floppy boot if it had issues, and I did it!*).

Comment: It's more convenient to do a normal dual boot, however it's possible to install the bootloader to whatever storage device you specify via the "Something else" (manual partitioning) option of the Ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

It's more convenient to install Ubuntu as a normal dual boot, however it's possible to install the bootloader to whatever storage device you specify via the "Something else" (manual partitioning) option of the *Installation type* screen Ubuntu installer.